# Returning to last ActionResult after HttpPost request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am current working on a MVC C# application and have a HttpPost ActionResult which adds a new role to a user. I want to use this method throughout my application.

The problem I have is once this method has run I want it to return to the previous ActionResult and as I want to reuse this method I can not set the return view to a set view. Is there a way to set the return to the previous View?

Many Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Your question does not make a lot of sense, what do you mean by the "previous view" or "previous actionresult".  A method (wither an mvc action or not) has no intrinsic way of knowing anything that happened during previous invocations.  If you want to maintain some kind of state you would have to use a static property or field or something like a session variable.

Comment: I mean the view when the HttpPost came from. i.e if it came from a view called Home it would redirect to this view. If its doesnt know what happened previously I guess I'll have to pass this information in the HttpPost request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a returnUrl when invoking the POST controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string returnUrl)
{
    .... do something
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

This way you can POST to this controller action from different parts of the application and every time you will provide the return url you want to get redirected to once it has finished processing. This is for example how the LogOn action in the default template works. You may take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It will by default return the view which is the same name as the action, not which view the form was submitted from.

If you want to return a specific view then you can do:

```
return View("ViewName",Model);
```

If you want to return the view that submitted the form you will need to *tell* the action where it came from, so you can add a property to your viewmodel that was set in the view. Then you could do:

```
return View(ViewModel.ViewName,ViewModel);
```

You might be able to do something nasty by digging the viewname out of the request object, but that is so horrible I am not going to even tell you where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ActionFilter` which uses a cookie to store the current route values. It loads the previously saved cookie in `OnActionExecuting` and stores the current route valeus in `OnActionExecuted`. But it will fail for everyone that has disabled cookies.

You could also use the HTTP header [Referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer). But it isn't set all the time.

There are in other words no reliable way to achieve what you want (without using a parameter as described by Darin). At least not a way which is worth the trouble.